# How to execute at the same height as an entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

My problem is that I want to give every player on the same height as an area_effect_cloud within a radius of 25 blocks a scoreboard called 'stunned'.

The command for that would look something like this:

```
/execute @e[type=area_effect_cloud] ~ ~ ~ /scoreboard players set @a[y=~,r=25] stunned 1
```

But the only problem is that the `y=~` is not a thing in Minecraft, does anyone have a solution to this, that isn't 1 or more command block for every height?

Comment: This probably becomes easier in 1.13 with the new execute functionality, but it should be possible in 1.12.

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it, you just have to make a huge, flat box that takes the y coordinate of the entity, but ignores x and z. Like this:

```
/execute at @e[type=area_effect_cloud] run scoreboard players set @a[x=-30000000,z=-30000000,dx=60000000,dz=60000000,dy=1] stunned 1
```

Notice that I use values for `dx`, `dy` and `dz`, but only offset `x` and `z`, not `y`, that way the game takes the y coordinate of the entity.

If you have a fixed y coordinate, you can also use this for a tiny bit of less lag:

```
/execute positioned <coordinates> run scoreboard players set @a[x=-30000000,z=-30000000,dx=60000000,dz=60000000,dy=1] stunned 1
```

And if "stunned" is only ever 1 or 0, you can use [tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/tag) ([archive](https://minecraft.wiki/w/index.php?title=Commands/tag&oldid=1241602)) instead.